# List the dependencies of a package regardless of how it is loaded or installed

Tags: r, r-package

I am looking for a slick way to programmatically get the `Imports:` and `Depends:` packages of a package. The trick is that the method should work regardless of whether the package is

1. installed or just loaded with `devtools::load_all()`, or
2. attached or just available through the namespace.

Desired functionality:

```
package_deps("dplyr")
## [1] "assertthat" "bindrcpp"   "glue"       "magrittr"   "methods"    "pkgconfig" 
## [7] "rlang"      "R6"         "Rcpp"       "tibble"     "utils"
```

Notice that the version numbers are all stripped away.

I am writing this post because it seems like this should already exist. (After all, `install.packages()` needs similar functionality.) I would rather not have to manage all the special cases myself.

Comment: [This section in Hadley's book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html#dependencies) does not seem to cover how to identify dependencies programmatically. [miniCRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/vignettes/miniCRAN-dependency-graph.html) looks at the CRAN version, not the version currently loaded, so it may not help me in development. This is meant to solve [a drake issue](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/issues/91). parLapply() needs drake's dependencies loaded on the "cluster", and I want to identify them programmatically if possible.

Comment: And I would rather not reinvent any wheels.

Comment: Forgot to mention: `tools::load_dependencies()` pulls from `available.packages()` or similar database that I would have to supply. If CRAN `drake` is already installed, for example, `tools::load_dependencies("drake")` ignores the version I load with `devtools::load_all("drake")` or the one loaded for `devtools::check("drake")`.

Comment: Similarly unhelpful: `tools::dependsOnPkgs()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pacman package that I maintain does this:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_depends(dplyr)

$Imports
 [1] "assertthat" "bindrcpp"   "glue"       "magrittr"   "methods"   
 [6] "pkgconfig"  "rlang"      "R6"         "Rcpp"       "tibble"    
[11] "utils"     

$LinkingTo
[1] "Rcpp"     "BH"       "bindrcpp" "plogr"   

$Suggests
 [1] "bit64"          "covr"           "dbplyr"         "dtplyr"        
 [5] "DBI"            "ggplot2"        "hms"            "knitr"         
 [9] "Lahman"         "mgcv"           "microbenchmark" "nycflights13"  
[13] "rmarkdown"      "RMySQL"         "RPostgreSQL"    "RSQLite"       
[17] "testthat"       "withr"
```

Comment: Perfect! `pacman` does exactly what I want, and it works like a dream for my edge case. I am glad this turned out to be such an easy fix.